# Appending to Postgres json array (not jsonb)

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonb

I'm trying out the json (and jsonb) support in postgres.
Currently the thing that has me stuck is how to append to a json array - I can do it with jsonb, but cannot work out if this is possible out of the box.

in jsonb:

```
CREATE TABLE OrderData (
    uuid text NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY UNIQUE,
    info jsonb NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO orderdata
VALUES('abcd','[{"items": {"product": "Jelly","qty": 1});

UPDATE orderdata SET info = info || '{"items": {"product": "Grape","qty": 10}}'::jsonb WHERE uuid LIKE 'abcd';
```

The above works fine - and I can do a `SELECT * FROM orderdata;` to see the updates.

When I'm doing the same thing with json - i can get it started off:

```
CREATE TABLE OrderData (
    uuid text NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY UNIQUE,
    info json NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO orderdata
VALUES('abcd','{"items": {"product": "Jelly","qty": 1}}'));
```

but then I can't use the `||` operator as it doesn't work on json (only jsonb).

Comment: If you manipulate the data inside the database, always use `jsonb`. Never use `json` in that case.

Comment: Unrelated, but: a UUID should be stored in a column defined with the type `uuid` not as `text`

Comment: As a workaround you can typecast the json string/column to/from jsonb and do the neccessary operations.

Comment: The JSON value is an array itself. What if you have more than one entry with the key `items` in the outer most array?

Comment: the above is just an example database - and has no relation to what will be used in the final (start) iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you insist on using `json` you have to cast your column to `jsonb`every time you want to do something useful:

```
UPDATE orderdata
   SET info = info::jsonb || '{"items": {"product": "Grape","qty": 10}}'
WHERE uuid = 'abcd'
```

Postgres will automatically cast the result of the expression on the right side of the `=` back to JSON in the assignment.